# How to design a block diagram

Tags: diagrams, block

Hello I was wondering how to do block diagrams in Latex. I am a beginner to the program so I am pretty remedial at it so far. I want to create

[image]

just without the bold lines or gray blocks. I am having trouble connecting everything and putting blocks in parallel or series. So far I have only been able to do a very simple one. Can I get some help please, thank you.

```
     \tikzset{
block/.style={
  draw, 
  fill=blue!20, 
  rectangle, 
  minimum height=3em, 
  minimum width=6em
  },
sum/.style={
  draw, 
  fill=blue!20, 
  circle, 
  },
input/.style={coordinate},
output/.style={coordinate},
pinstyle/.style={
  pin edge={to-,thin,black}
  }
}  


% The block diagram code is probably more verbose than necessary
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex']
    % We start by placing the blocks
    \node [input, name=input] {};
    \node [sum, right = of input] (sum) {};
    \node [block, right = of sum] (controller) {$K_d$};
    \node [block, right = of controller, pin={[pinstyle]above:$f(t)$},
            node distance=3cm] (system) {$G(s)$};
    % We draw an edge between the controller and system block to 
    % calculate the coordinate u. We need it to place the measurement block. 
    \draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=u] {} (system);
    \node [output, right =of system] (output) {};
    %\node [block, below of=u] (measurements) {Measurements};

    % Once the nodes are placed, connecting them is easy. 
    \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$r$} (sum);
    \draw [->] (sum) -- node {} (controller);
    \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$x$}(output);
    \draw [->] (y) -- ++(0,-2cm) -| node[pos=0.99] {} 
        node [near end] {} (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: you can use  https://ctan.org/pkg/schemabloc

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way. It uses a chain, and you can change the edge labels on the spot with `[el=<label>]`. By "upgrading" styles when necessary we can thus avoid having to add all the joins by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=Latex,
    cnode/.style={},    
    block/.style={cnode,
      draw, 
      fill=blue!20, 
      rectangle, 
      minimum height=3em, 
      minimum width=6em
      },
      tblock/.style={block,minimum width=2em},
    sum/.style={cnode,
      draw, 
      fill=blue!20, 
      circle, 
      },
    input/.style={coordinate,cnode},
    output/.style={coordinate,cnode},
    arj/.style={-Latex,semithick}]
    %
    \begin{scope}[start chain=R going right,
        cnode/.append style={join=by arj,on chain},
        node distance=2.5em,
        arj/.append style={edge label=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/el}},
        el/.initial={}]
     \path node[input]{}    
          [el={$r$}]    
          node[tblock,alias=Nbar]{$\overline{N}$}
          [el={}]
          node[sum,label=above left:{$+$},label=below right:{$-$}]{}
          [el={$u$}]
          node[tblock,alias=B]{$B$}
          [el={},arj/.append style={very thick}]
          node[sum,label=above left:{$+$},label=below right:{$+$}]{}
          [el={$\dot x$}]
          node[tblock,alias=o]{$1/s$}
          [el={$x$}]
          node[tblock,alias=C,xshift=3em]{$C$}
          [el={$y$}]
          node[output]{};    
    \end{scope}
    %
    \begin{scope}[start chain=D going below,
        cnode/.append style={on chain},
        node distance=2.5em]
     \chainin (o);
     \node[tblock,alias=A]{$A$};    
     \node[tblock,alias=K]{$K$};    
    \end{scope}     
    %
    \path (o) -- (C) coordinate[pos=1/3] (oC1) coordinate[pos=2/3] (oC2);
    \draw[arj] (K) -| (R-2);
    \tikzset{arj/.append style={very thick}}
    \draw[arj] (A) -| (R-5);
    \draw[arj] (oC1) |- (A);
    \draw[arj] (oC2) |- (K);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use 
https://ctan.org/pkg/schemabloc

Comment: @rpapa Merci! If you post an answer I can study it... ;-)

Comment: the answer is below

Answer (score 2):

Another way is:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 6mm,
  start chain = going right,
  base/.style = {draw, fill=blue!20},
 block/.style = {base, minimum height=2em, minimum width=3em},
   sum/.style = {base, circle, node contents={}},
   arr/.style = {ultra thick, -{Latex[length=5pt, width=6pt]}},
every edge/.style = {draw, -Latex},
                        ]
% We start by placing the blocks in chain
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain}]
\coordinate (in);
\node (n1)  [block]    {$\bar{N}$};
\node (n2)  [sum];
\node (n3)  [block]  {$B$};
\node (n4)  [sum];
\node (n5)  [block]  {$1/s$};
\coordinate (n6);
\coordinate (n7);
\node (n8) [block]     {$C$};
\coordinate (out);
    \end{scope}
%
\path   (in) edge["$r$"]   (n1)
        (n1) edge[near end,"+"] (n2)
        (n2) edge["$u$"]                    (n3)
        (n3) edge[arr,near end,"+"]         (n4)
        (n4) edge[arr,"$\dot{\mathbf{x}}$"] (n5)
        (n5) edge[arr,"$\mathbf{x}$"]       (n8)
        (n8) edge[arr,"$\mathbf{y}$"]       (out);
% Block in backloops
\node (n11)  [block, below=of n5]  {$A$};
\node (n12)  [block, below=of n11] {$K$};
%       
\draw[arr]  (n6)  |- (n11);
\draw[arr]  (n11) -| (n4) node[below right] {$+$};
\draw[arr]  (n7)  |- (n12);
\draw[-Latex]  (n12) -| (n2) node[below right] {$-$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal using the block diagram package on the ctan.

https://ctan.org/pkg/schemabloc

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{schemabloc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\sbEntree{E}
\sbBlocL{B1}{$\overline{N}$}{E}
    \sbRelier[$r$]{E}{B1}
\sbComp*{C1}{B1}
    \sbRelier{B1}{C1}
\sbStyleBloc{blue,very thick,fill=yellow,text=red}%
\sbBloc{B2}{$B$}{C1}
    \sbRelier[$u$]{C1}{B2}
\sbSumb*{C2}{B2}
    \sbRelier{B2}{C2}
\sbBloc{B3}{$\frac{1}{s}$}{C2}
    \sbRelier[$\dot{x}$]{C2}{B3}
\sbBloc[6]{B4}{$C$}{B3}
    \sbRelier[$x$]{B3}{B4}
\sbSortie[4]{Y}{B4}

\sbStyleBloc{very thick,fill=green,text=blue}%
    \sbRelier[$y$]{B4}{Y}
    \sbDecaleNoeudy{B3}{R3}
\sbStyleLien{ultra thick, red}
    \sbBlocr[-1.5]{R3}{$A$}{R3}
        \sbRelieryx{B3-B4}{R3}
        \sbRelierxy{R3}{C2}
    \sbDecaleNoeudy[9]{B3}{R4}
    \sbBlocr[-1.5]{R4}{$K$}{R4}
        \sbRelieryx{B3-B4}{R4}
        \sbRelierxy{R4}{C1}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]